# Solutions of $e^x-1-k\cdot \arctan{x}=0$,

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, trigonometry

consider $h(x)=e^x-1-k\cdot\arctan{x}$,then find on which condition on $k$ there will be two solutions for $h(x)=0$ ($k$ is real).

> I let $f(x)=e^x-1$ and $g(x)=k.\arctan{x}$ and let $f(x)-g(x)=0$ has roots $0$ and $y$. I found that if $y$ tends to $0$ then $k$ tends to $1$. How to do further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x=0$ is always one of the solutions. Then the function

$$f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{\arctan x}$$ can be shown to be strictly increasing and has an horizontal asymptote

$$y=\frac2\pi.$$

You can conclude.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x=0$ is the essential root of $f(x)=0$. $$f(x)=e^{x} -1 -k\tan^{-1} x \implies  f'(x)= e^x-k/(1+x^2) \implies f''(x)=e^x+2kx/(1+x^2)$$
$f(-\infty)=1+k\pi/2$ and $f(\infty)= +\infty.$ So $f(x)=0$ will have even number  $(0,2,4,...)$ of real  roots in $(-\infty, \infty)$ if $f(-\infty) >0 \implies  k >2/\pi$. So this eq. will have 2 real roots if $k>2/\pi$.